# Calculate feature extent OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, features, well-known-text

I have a feature created from Well Known Text as following:

```
var feature = format.readFeature(wkt , {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:25830',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:25830'
});
```

When I add it to a layer and try to center in the map like this:

```
this.vectorSource.addFeatures(feature);
this.map.getView().fit(feature.values_.geometry.extent_, {duration: 2500});
```

I get an `AssertionError`. When analyzing the feature I find the extent is set to infinity:

```
extent_: (4) [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]
```

> How can I calculate the feature extent? How can I zoom and center the
>   created feature on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple:

Just replacing

```
feature.values_.geometry.extent_
```

with

```
feature.getGeometry().getExtent()
```

That worked fine.